# Is there any way of recording an AR session in unity instead of using a screen recorder

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, mediarecorder

Here's regarding the unity AR foundation integrated into a react native app. I was able to implement a feature so that the unity AR session could be recorded by using a native screen recorder functionality integrated to the AR app using AR foundation. The problem there is that it records all the things in the screen including if the notifications received while recording. Got a workaround for android(enabling do not disturb) but there's no workaround for iOS. So looking for any solution from unity side or native side that record only the AR session related stuff instead of using the screen recorder thing.(This was previously doable with NatCorder in the unity asset store but now it's deprecated)